# Usage of ArrayList instead of Map in OkHttp

Tags: java, android, data-structures, okhttp

I was going through the source of the Header class in okhttp3; For storing headers and the corresponding values, an `ArrayList` is used; So for first key 0, it's value will be at 1 and so on...

This is the method that does this work:

```java
final List<String> namesAndValues = new ArrayList<>(20);

Builder addLenient(String name, String value) {
      namesAndValues.add(name);
      namesAndValues.add(value.trim());
      return this;
    }
```

So I just want to know the reason behind using an `ArrayList` instead of a Map like data structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Header usually are presented with multimap  `Map<String,List<String>>`

It seems internally they have decided to use a single list which serves the same purpose. Initially was even an array. I would say it is more a develop preference, as this is internal code and it is hidden for the audience.

Possible could be to save some memory instead of using multimap  and less garbage - imagine having 10 headers it will be a map with 10 lists + the items inside.(Usually these are created on every http request)

Headers class should have also a method `toMultimap`

Comment: Yep! This also preserves the total order of headers, so if you have `Cookie`, `User-Agent`, `Cookie` this structure makes that easy.

Comment: So this means that a single header key can have multiple values; Like Auth="auth1" and Auth="auth2"; Is it possible to have two values? Also if this is the case then it would actually break the [get method](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/Headers.kt#L334) from the `Header` class as it returns as soon as it finds the last key as it is traversing from the end in the ArrayList.

Comment: @VishalAmbre Yes, multiple values for same header are allowed. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Headers.java#107

```["Auth","auth1","Auth","auth2"] ```-  This is how it will be presented underlying with the list.

Comment: But doesn't it mean that the `get` method is buggy https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Headers.java#148 as it will return only the last value for the header key

Comment: @VishalAmbre No, it works as per javadoc. 

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-headers/get/

If you expect more values per given header name use https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-headers/values/